# How do you correctly test that an error is raised in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I'm testing an Interactor in Rails with `assert_raise` and I'm passing arguments to it that should not raise an error.

However, the `assert_raise` on that Interactor call doesnt fail, rendering a false positive.

interactor:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Crm::ListTags
  include Interactor

  before do
    context.adapter ||= CrmAdapter.new
  end

  delegate :contact_id, :adapter, to: :context

  def call
    response = adapter.list_contact_tags(contact_id)
    context.contact_tags = response.body["contactTags"]
    return if response.success?

    raise StandardError.new "#{self.class} ERROR: #{response.body['message']}"
  end
end
```

test:

```
VCR.use_cassette("crm.active_campaign.retrieve_contact_tags_for_contact.successful") do
      response = Crm::ListTags.call(adapter: @adapter, contact_id: contact_id)
      assert response.success? # assertion success
      assert_raise StandardError do
        Crm::ListTags.call(adapter: @adapter, contact_id: contact_id) # assertion should fail but doesn't (as if it were reaching the error)
      end
    end
```

As you can see I'm passing the same arguments to both Interactor calls. The second one should fail because it should not reach the error that it expects to. However it doesnt.

Comment: Is this a trick question? Like, does `Crm::ListTags.call` actually mutate the value of `@adapter`, causing it to raise an exception the second time it's called? Or are you actually running the wrong test? :D

Comment: What happens if you do: `assert_raise(StandardError) { puts "Hello World" }` ? Does that fail?

Comment: @TomLord printing "Hello World" efectively makes the assertion fail (StandardError expected but nothing was raised). I don't understand your first comment. I'm calling the Interactor with valid arguments (so it should not raise an error) but I don't get a failure for that. Don't mind the adapter. The interactos accepts an adapter or it instantiates it's own. I added the Interactor for context.

Comment: I don't really understand your code, because `Crm::ListTags.call` takes no arguments, but you're passing two named parameters -- so how is that working? Does `include Interactor` do some weird magic? Anyway..... Are you *really, really, 100% sure* that `Crm::ListTags.call(...)` does **not** raise an exception, the second time you're calling it?

Comment: Sorry, that's because it's an Interactor, and anything passed to it is added to the context which is like a hash that stores key-values. I'm 100% sure it's not raising an error. If I use the same exact arguments to call it from the console, it doesn't raise an error. The same should happen in the test, failing the assertion that checks that an error is raised.

Comment: Forget the console for a moment, what happens if you comment out the line: `assert_raise StandardError do` (and the `end` below it)? Make sure you're running the exact same code, in the exact same context. Sorry for sounding so anal, I just do not believe you've found a bug in the core ruby testing framework haha

Comment: Oooh.... For example, here's what it could be: Maybe you've set `allow_playback_repeats` to `false` for VCR? So it's trying to replay the response twice, and thereby raising an exception? In which case if you followed my advice and run the code *in the context of the test*, not in some other console environment, you'll see it raises an exception?

Comment: @TomLord Thanks. I moved the assert_raise to the top of the VCR block, making it the first thing it tests and it works correctly now! (raising an error if the arguments are invalid). As to why it was not working, I haven't figured it out yet. Any idea what's the difference?

Comment: Without actually seeing the new code nor the error message, it's really hard for me to pass any comment

Comment: Incidentally though, this is an excellent example why it's generally bad practice to `raise StandardError.new ...` (or equivalently, just typing `raise "a string"`). Because by using the generic error class, it's hard to isolate which errors are "yours" vs anything else. A better idea would be to create a custom exception class (a class that inherits from `StandardError`) - which you can test for more explicitly.